# Abstract class which uses a abstract factory -> New implementation with Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I have a abstract class which is extended by many many other classes:

**What I have done:**

```
public abstract class AbstractActionHandler {

    protected WorkItem currentWI;
    protected String status;
    protected String field;

    protected void init(WorkItem currentWI, String status, String field) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
      this.currentWI = currentWI;
      this.status = status;
      this.field = field;
      if(couldBeExecuted()) {
        this.executeAction();
      }
    }

    protected boolean couldBeExecuted() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      DataObjectFactory fact = DataObjectFactory.getFactory(currentWI);
      DataWorkItem currentWI = fact.getDataWorkItem("current");
      long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("+++++ " + " Workitem Factory takes " + (end-start) + "ms " + "+++++");

      // Other logic which returns false or true
      // [...]
    }
    // Implementation of business logic
    protected abstract void executeAction();
    // Should call init function
    public void execute(WorkItem currentWI, String status, String field) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.init(currentWI, status, field);
    }

}
```

Now I figured out that the creation of `DataWorkItem` object takes a lot of time. Because I am using an abstract factory I can simply change the line

`DataObjectFactory fact = DataObjectFactory.getFactory(currentWI);`

to

`DataObjectFactory fact = DataObjectFactory.getBoostFactory(currentWI);`

and provide another implementation of `DataWorkItem` object.

Old implementation which calls an external API function which needs a lot of time and which is basically only necessary to call once:

```
public DataWorkItem(IWorkItem wi, String revision) {
       OtherExternService externService = (OtherExternService) PlatformContext
       .getPlatform().lookupService(OtherExternService.class);  
       IPObjectList listOfRevs = externService.getDataService().getObjectHistory(wi);
}
```

New implementation which calls API function only one time because of singleton implementation:

```
public DataWorkItem(WorkItem wi, String revision, boolean global) {
        // +++
        // We use a global object here which holds the history of current work item.
        // We only need to read this history once so we create a singleton here.
        // The performance is hardly improved by this pattern.
        // We use this constructor in DataBoostObjectFactory.
        // +++
        IPObjectList listOfRevs = WorkItemGlobal.getInstance(wi).getObjectList();           
}
```

**Singleton class:**

```
public class WorkItemGlobal {

    public static WorkItemGlobal instance = null;
    private IPObjectList listOfRevs;

    private WorkItemGlobal(WorkItem wi) {
       OtherExternService externService = (OtherExternService) PlatformContext
       .getPlatform().lookupService(OtherExternService.class);  
       listOfRevs = externService.getDataService().getObjectHistory(wi);
    }

    public static WorkItemGlobal getInstance(WorkItem wi) {
       if(instance == null) {
           instance = new WorkItemGlobal(wi);
       }
       return instance;
    }

    public static void deleteInstance() {
       instance = null;
    }

    public IPObjectList getObjectList() {
       return listOfRevs;
    }

}
```

**Question:**

Is it good to use a Singleton here?

Of course I can avoid using a singleton if I create the `DataWorkItem` object outside of the classes which extends `AbstractActionHandler` and pass the object to the constructor (for example).

But with this approach I have to adjust ALL classes which extends `AbstractActionHandler` because I have to call a function (or change constructor) which passes the `DataWorkItem` object to the abstract class.

At all it works good (for now). I can see a hardly improved performance because the call to the external API function is only done once.

Other suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is: **Is it good to use a Singleton here?**

My answer is: **If you can avoid** using a singleton, do it! And you answer this yourself: "Of course I can avoid using a singleton if (...)".

Passing a `DataWorkItem` object to the constructor or some other method is more preferable than using a singleton-pattern. This is part of the principle [Tell, don't ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).

The `deleteInstance` method in your "singleton" defies the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which states that it

> restricts the Instantiation of a class to one object.

By using a `deleteInstance` method, you allow multiple objects. (Not at the same time, but still multiple objects).

**Other comments**

You have one field `protected WorkItem currentWI;` and one local variable in your `couldBeExecuted` method: `DataWorkItem currentWI = fact.get..`. They share the same variable name. This leads to confusion for me. I don't see much of your field. (Of course, I don't see your subclasses to this method). You might want to pass the object on to the methods instead of storing it as a field (again with the principle **Tell, don't ask). Will that object ever be used again after `init` has been called? If not, remove it.

In your `DataWorkItem`, you declare a new local variable **on the last line of the constructor**

```
IPObjectList listOfRevs = externService.getDataService().getObjectHistory(wi);
```

This should give you a "unused variable" warning from the compiler. What happens to this variable once the method is finished? Nothing!

Comment: Thank you for your comments! You are right. One of the "currentWI" variable should be renamed -> done. The protected currentWI field is used by sub classes. After the last line "IPObjectList listOfRevs = externService.getDataService().getObjectHistory(wi);" in my question there is also other relevant code which uses "listOfRevs". I forgot to comment that other code follows. However, you answer my question to avoid the Singleton (because it is just possible...independing of the effort).